# JQuery change value attr of multiple generated HTML elements

Tags: jquery, html, attributes

I have the following problem:

I want to generate HTML elements with JQuery onbuttonclick which works fine.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#add_more').click(function() {
    $(this).before($("<div/>", {
        id: 'filediv'
    }).fadeIn('slow').append($("<input/>", {
        name: 'file[]',
        type: 'file',
        id: 'file'
    }), $("<br/><br/>")));
});
```

HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="maindiv">
<div id="formdiv">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
        First Field is Compulsory. Only JPEG,PNG,JPG Type Image Uploaded. Image Size Should Be Less Than 10MB.<br/><br/>
    <div id="filediv">
        <input name="imagetitle" type="text" class="imagetitle" placeholder="Choose image title" value=""><br>
        <input name="file[]" type="file" id="file"/><br><br>
    </div>
        <input type="button" id="add_more" class="upload" value="Add More Files"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit" id="upload" class="upload"/>
    </form>

    <?php include "upload.php"; ?>
</div>
</div>
```

So the elements will be generatedlike I want them to be generated.
Now I want the HTML "value" attribute to be changed when the user changes the text, which also works great.

```
$('.imagetitle').change(function(){
    var text = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(text);
    $(this).attr("value", text);
});
```

Now the problem... If I generate a second HTML inputbox and change the value by entering a new text, it won't be changed.

This is the first element(change the value works)
[image: This is the first element(change the value works)]

This is the second element(does not work)
[image: This is the second element(does not work)]

Can somebody explain to me what is going on here and what my mistake is?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: why you don't do a file input that accepts more than one image and just show the thumbnails?

Comment: @I'mBlueDaBaDee Dee that's what I did. But I did not list the whole code, so it won't get to messy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegate your change event, you have dynamically added elements so the event does not trigger for the appended ones, event delegation bubbles the click event form a static element `body` to the dynamically added element `.imagetitle`:

```
$('body').on('change','.imagetitle',function(){
    var text = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(text);
    $(this).attr("value", text);
});
```

Remove the id from the file input or change the id to a class

Comment: Wow thank you, this worked, what what does this has to do with the file id?

Comment: id's are usually unique in javascript when you search for a id it will return only the first element with that id

Comment: aaah now I get it what you mean. Stupid me :D

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is event delegation. This means that jQuery cannot bind events after the page has loaded.

The way to combat this is to use the `on` function instead. For example:

```
$('.imagetitle').change(function(){
    var text = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(text);
    $(this).attr("value", text);
});
```

Can be changed to:

```
$('.imagetitle').on('change', function(){
    var text = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(text);
    $(this).attr("value", text);
});
```

Which should allow jQuery to bind the change event to the appropriate elements.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things to consider, first of all, if your html is getting generated after DOM ready via java-script you need event delegation to bind the event with the elements which are added dynamically like:

```
$("#formdiv").on("change",".imagetitle",function(){
    var text = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(text);
    $(this).attr("value", text);
});
```

another thing is that, do not render multiple elements with same id, it will be invalid html, instead you can use class attribute like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#add_more').click(function() {
    $(this).before($("<div/>", {
        class: 'filediv' // use class attribute instead
    }).fadeIn('slow').append($("<input/>", {
        name: 'file[]',
        type: 'file',
        id: 'file'
    }), $("<br/><br/>")));
});
```